# What is the attack surface of CVE-2014-3802?

Tags: cve

[CVE-2014-3802](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2014-3802) says that it

> allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service (memory corruption) via a crafted PDB file.

The [ZDI page](https://www.zerodayinitiative.com/advisories/ZDI-14-129/) says that:

> User interaction is required to exploit this vulnerability in that the target must visit a malicious page or open a malicious file.

I'm unclear on how this vulnerability is activated. PDB files are used when debugging programs, does this mean that the vulnerability is only present when someone placed a malicious PDB file on the target machine and is debugging the program?

Answer (score 1):

The vulnerability is present regardless of the existence of a malicious file. The malicious file ***exploits*** the vulnerability that exists.

And you have the rest correct. The local user (or a remote user with interactive access to the system (RDP, etc.)) needs to open the malicious file.

Comment: I understand that the attacker must be able to place a malicious PDB file on the system but in order to activate a PDB (and get the permission of the running process), my understanding is that the user needs to **debug** the process (so that the PDB is loaded).